# cancelling a tap gesture recongiser

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uitapgesturerecognizer

Referring to my last question:

[Sprite moves two places after being paused and then unpaused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801518/sprite-moves-two-places-after-being-paused-and-then-unpaused)

Hi, I have a tap gesture which moves a sprite in my game forward 1 space and when I press the pause button it continues to register the tap gesture and then when I resume the gameplay It moves two spaces.

so I managed to define a bool variable that detects (using if statements) if I have paused the tap gesture

```
var tapIsPaused: Bool = false



func tapUp(){

    if(tapIsPaused == true) {

        //do nothing


    } else if (tapIsPaused == false) {

        let amountToMove:CGFloat = levelUnitHeight

        let move:SKAction = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: amountToMove, duration: 0.1)


        menubutton.hidden = true
        settingsButton.hidden = true
        highscoreLabel.hidden = true
        pauseButton.hidden = false

        thePlayer.runAction(move)

        clearNodes()

    }

}
```

But the problem I have now is that when I press the resume button to resume the gameplay it still moves the sprite, but this time it's only moving one space up, which is because when I press the resume button it turns the tap on which then registers the tap of the resume button to move the player up.

How can I fix this?

**Here is my pause button:**

```
 else if (node == pauseButton) {

        tapIsPaused = true
        pauseButton.removeFromParent()
        addChild(resumeButton)
        addChild(restartButton)
        self.runAction (SKAction.runBlock(self.pauseGame))

    }
```

**Here is my resume button:**

```
 else if (node == resumeButton) {


        resumeButton.removeFromParent()
        restartButton.removeFromParent()
        addChild(pauseButton)
        self.runAction (SKAction.runBlock(self.resumeGame))
        tapIsPaused = false

    }
```

Here is my tap gesture handler code:

```
 let TapUpRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()




 TapUpRec.addTarget(self, action: "tapUp")
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(TapUpRec)
```

Comment: try putting `tapIsPaused = false` before you call the runAction method in your code for resume button

Comment: I suggest you post your tap gesture handler code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove Gesture on Pause click using following:

```
self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(YOUR_GESTURE_RECOGNISER)
```

and add it again if resume game

Comment: You legend. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your resume function as:

```
 else if (node == resumeButton) {

    resumeButton.removeFromParent()
    restartButton.removeFromParent()
    addChild(pauseButton)
    tapIsPaused = false
    self.runAction (SKAction.runBlock(self.resumeGame))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple and easiest way.No need to add or remove Gesture.

You can do it with enable or disable your gesture.

**For swift 2.3**

```
TapUpRec.enabled = false //pause click

TapUpRec.enabled = true //resume click
```

**For swift 3.0**

```
TapUpRec.isEnabled = false //pause click

TapUpRec.isEnabled = true //resume click
```