# Swift 2.0, SpriteKit - Scrollview to not use pages.

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, sprite-kit

Ok so I have a scrollView which has been subclassed to be able to be applied to any scene which is from a previous question I asked here:

[SpriteKit, Swift 2.0 - ScrollView in reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712427/spritekit-swift-2-0-scrollview-in-reverse)

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

/// Nodes touched
var nodesTouched: [AnyObject] = [] // global

/// Scroll direction
enum ScrollDirection: Int {
case None = 0
case Vertical
case Horizontal
}

class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {

// MARK: - Static Properties

/// Touches allowed
static var disabledTouches = false

/// Scroll view
private static var scrollView: UIScrollView!

// MARK: - Properties

/// Current scene
private weak var currentScene: SKScene?

/// Moveable node
private var moveableNode: SKNode?

/// Scroll direction
private var scrollDirection = ScrollDirection.None

// MARK: - Init
init(frame: CGRect, scene: SKScene, moveableNode: SKNode, scrollDirection: ScrollDirection) {
    print("Scroll View init")
    super.init(frame: frame)

    CustomScrollView.scrollView = self
    self.scrollDirection = scrollDirection
    self.currentScene = scene
    self.moveableNode = moveableNode
    self.frame = frame
    indicatorStyle = .White
    scrollEnabled = true
    //self.minimumZoomScale = 1
    //self.maximumZoomScale = 3
    canCancelContentTouches = false
    userInteractionEnabled = true
    delegate = self

    // flip for spritekit (only needed for horizontal)
    if self.scrollDirection == .Horizontal {
        let flip = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1,-1)
        self.transform = flip
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

 // MARK: - Touches
 extension CustomScrollView {

/// began
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("Touch began scroll view")

    guard !CustomScrollView.disabledTouches else { return }
    currentScene?.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}

/// moved
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("Touch moved scroll view")

    guard !CustomScrollView.disabledTouches else { return }
    currentScene?.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
}

/// ended
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("Touch ended scroll view")

    guard !CustomScrollView.disabledTouches else { return }
    currentScene?.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
}

/// cancelled
override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("Touch cancelled scroll view")

    guard !CustomScrollView.disabledTouches else { return }
    currentScene?.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)
   }
}

 // MARK: - Touch Controls
 extension CustomScrollView {

/// Disable
class func disable() {
    print("Disabled scroll view")
    CustomScrollView.scrollView?.userInteractionEnabled = false
    CustomScrollView.disabledTouches = true
}

/// Enable
class func enable() {
    print("Enabled scroll view")
    CustomScrollView.scrollView?.userInteractionEnabled = true
    CustomScrollView.disabledTouches = false
   }
 }

 // MARK: - Delegates
 extension CustomScrollView: UIScrollViewDelegate {

/// did scroll
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("Scroll view did scroll")

    if scrollDirection == .Horizontal {
        moveableNode!.position.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    } else {
        moveableNode!.position.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y
      }
    }
 }
```

The only problem is that the scrollview uses pages, while, the way I want it to look, scrolls only through the sprites, like the raywenderlich one where all the sprites are the only things moving and so I don't have to scroll across multiple pages to get to a sprite.

the project can be found here:

[Raywenderlich Project](http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/SwiftSV-21-Sprite-Kit-Level-Selector-I-demo-finished-1_0.zip)

Because they use their gameViewController I am having trouble figuring out how to implement it through a subclass scrollview like I have above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont understand what you are asking here. I just checked the RayWenderlich tutorial and its exactly the same as my GitHub sample project. They just keep the sprites closer together where as in my project for demonstration purposes I put each sprite on a new page.

If you just want sprites to scroll that just add the sprites to the moveableNode and the rest as usual to the scene directly.

```
addChild(background)
moveableNode.addChild(sprite1)
```

Than change the sprite positions so they are closer together. You basically add the 1st sprite to the 1st page in the scrollView and than position the other sprites based on the previous sprites x position. You add these sprites to sprite1 as well.

```
let sprite1 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
sprite1.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
page1ScrollView.addChild(sprite1)

let sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
sprite2.position = CGPointMake(sprite1.position.x + (sprite2.size.width * 1.5), sprite1.position.y)
sprite1.addChild(sprite2)

let sprite3 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
sprite3.position = CGPointMake(sprite2.position.x + (sprite3.size.width * 1.5), sprite1.position.y)
sprite1.addChild(sprite3)
```

I updated my gitHub project to show this in action 
https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift2-SpriteKit-UIScrollView-Helper

Comment: I just tried what you stated above but the the sprites after sprite1 don't line up they just are half off the bottom part of the screen. also i can't see the 3rd one at all.

Comment: I just updated my answer, you need to add sprite 2,3 etc to sprite 1 "sprite1.addChild(sprite2)...". Just copy the updated code above again and see it work now

Comment: anyway to make then lock to a sprite after they finish scrolling rather than half on and half on a sprite? like the ray project has. (Should i ask another question?) if so i'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah most likely better to make a new question. I will gladly help with the new one too.

Comment: I also updated my answer to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801518/sprite-moves-two-places-after-being-paused-and-then-unpaused/34814630#34814630

Comment: here is the new question about the scroll locking and zooming http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889359/making-a-scrollview-lock-on-a-sprite-and-enlarging-it

Comment: So what do you think about the new question?

Comment: So are you going to help me with my question?

Comment: @cashoverride777 did you ever get a chance to take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889359/making-a-scrollview-lock-on-a-sprite-and-enlarging-it